# Explain timestamp for file being overwritten

Tags: filesystems, macos, aws

Can it be explained why the file that is being overwritten gets a different timestamp (10 Jan 18:43) during the write, and then when it's done it's all the same timestamp?

It was with aws s3 cp command (the AWS CLI) and macOS 12 today. I'm sure I can reproduce it. Wondering why it says 10 Jan 18:43 during the copying when that date should have nothing to do with any of it.

```
% ls -ahl 01/03
total 7736832
drwxr-xr-x   9 jj42  staff   288B 25 Jan 10:07 .
drwxr-xr-x  26 jj42  staff   832B 25 Jan 09:53 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 jj42  staff   421M  3 Jan 04:40 A42_w_RP_1.csv
-rw-r--r--   1 jj42  staff   471M  3 Jan 04:40 A42_w_RP_2.csv
-rw-r--r--   1 jj42  staff   577M  3 Jan 04:40 A42_w_RP_3.csv
-rw-r--r--   1 jj42  staff   687M 10 Jan 18:43 A42_w_RP_4.csv
-rw-r--r--   1 jj42  staff   680M 25 Jan 10:07 A42_w_RP_4.csv.F3BeE932
-rw-r--r--   1 jj42  staff   506M  3 Jan 04:40 A42_w_RP_5.csv
-rw-r--r--   1 jj42  staff   382M  3 Jan 04:40 A42_w_RP_6.csv

% ls -ahl 01/03
total 6327296
drwxr-xr-x   8 jj42  staff   256B 25 Jan 10:07 .
drwxr-xr-x  26 jj42  staff   832B 25 Jan 09:53 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 jj42  staff   421M  3 Jan 04:40 A42_w_RP_1.csv
-rw-r--r--   1 jj42  staff   471M  3 Jan 04:40 A42_w_RP_2.csv
-rw-r--r--   1 jj42  staff   577M  3 Jan 04:40 A42_w_RP_3.csv
-rw-r--r--   1 jj42  staff   687M  3 Jan 04:40 A42_w_RP_4.csv
-rw-r--r--   1 jj42  staff   506M  3 Jan 04:40 A42_w_RP_5.csv
-rw-r--r--   1 jj42  staff   382M  3 Jan 04:40 A42_w_RP_6.csv
% ls -ahl 01/03
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you use(d) rsync and it failed midway through syncing: `A42_w_RP_4.csv.F3BeE932`.